# Add incremental data attribute matching class names with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to set an incremental data attribute to a series of divs with a common class name.

For example, I have these divs:

```
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
```

And what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
<div class="field__item" data-foo="1">Test</div>
<div class="field__item" data-foo="2">Test</div>
<div class="field__item" data-foo="3">Test</div>
<div class="field__item" data-foo="4">Test</div>
<div class="field__item" data-foo="5">Test</div>
<div class="field__item" data-foo="6">Test</div>
<div class="field__item" data-foo="7">Test</div>
<div class="field__item" data-foo="8">Test</div>
```

I've been doing something like this:

```
const el = document.querySelector('.field__item');
let a = 1;
el.setAttribute('data-foo', (a++));
```

But that only sets the first div and I'm not sure how to get it to use something like a `forEach` to set that data attribute to all of them. I was trying this:

```
const item = document.querySelectorAll(".field__item");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(item, function(elements, index) {
  let a = 1;
  item.setAttribute("data-foo", a++);
});
```

But that errors out with the `item.setAttribute is not a function.`

Open to any suggestions.

Comment: Try `item[index]`, since item is a collection.

Comment: Your pluralization is problematic.  Instead of `item`, I would call it `items`, and the in your callback function, it should be `element` instead of `elements`.  That should help make it clear that you want to call **`element`**.setAttribute.  (Also note that you can call `forEach` directly on `items`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `.forEach()` directly from the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) returned from [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

The first parameter of a `.forEach()` is the current element, and the second parameter is the current index

```js
const item = document.querySelectorAll(".field__item");

item.forEach((element, index) => {
  element.setAttribute('data-foo', index);
});

// Just to demo the data change
item.forEach(element => console.log(element.getAttribute('data-foo')));
```

```html
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
<div class="field__item">Test</div>
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, ok cool. Yeah, I see it now. I'm slowing needing to un-ravel my brain from the jQuery ways so trying to figure things like this out I seem to need help on. Thanks!